# How to use Pinia without creating Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Right now we can access pinia store only with Vue app

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from './App.vue'
import mainStore from 'store/main.store';

const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)

const store = mainStore();
app.mount('#app')
```

But how we access  Pinia store without Vue app? Somehting like this, as it was done with vuex.

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import mainStore from 'store/main.store';

const pinia = createPinia()

const store = mainStore();
```

Comment: Consider explaining your case, this could be XY problem.

Comment: Just don't `app.mount('#app')`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, pinia is implemented using the vue plugin, and the pinia object is passed with provide() inject(), so it cannot run without the vue environment.